How does changing an account alias affect pre-configured flow connections?
I'm currently working with Power Automate and have several flow connections configured with a service account. Our organization is considering changing the alias of my account and I'm concerned about how this might impact my existing connections.

If I change the account alias after the flows have been configured, will this break the existing connections?
Are there specific steps I should follow to ensure that all connections remain intact after the alias change?
Is there any official documentation or best practices for managing this type of change?

I have reviewed the Power Automate documentation and checked various community forums but have not found a definitive answer regarding the impact of changing an account alias on existing flow connections. I expected to find a clear guideline or best practice but have only found fragmented information.
